# Create Azure Flask using Powershell

Tags: azure, flask, azure-powershell

I want to create Azure Flask using PowerShell like how we create Web App in powershell(refer below). Is there any command to do that.

> New-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $WebAppResourceGroupName -Name
>   $WebAppName -Location $WebAppLocation -AppServicePlan
>   $WebAppServicePlanName

Comment: there is no specific command for that, but I'm sure you can do that with Powershell, also you can do that with an ARM template

Comment: Can you please provide any example

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ARM Template to deploy Flask app:

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "hostingPlanName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "hostingEnvironment": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "serverFarmResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "properties": {
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": []
                },
                "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('hostingEnvironment')]"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
                    "name": "web",
                    "type": "sourcecontrols",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('name'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "RepoUrl": "https://github.com/azureappserviceoss/FlaskAzure",
                        "branch": "master",
                        "IsManualIntegration": true
                    }
                }
            ],
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {
                "[concat('hidden-related:', '/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "empty"
            }
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
}
```

You would store that in a file or on a url and invoke it with `New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment`

Comment: I am able to successfully create the web app. but i am error when i browser the web app

Comment: Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely. It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application.